# Placing different rows in succession

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've started working with access around 1 month ago and I'm actually making a tool for preventive medicine so they can use a digital version of their actual paper form.

While the program is nearly finished, the med who requested it now wants to export to excel (the easy part) all the data from a patient his treatment and all the medicines used during that treatment in a single line (the problem).

I've been beating my head over that for two days, trying and researching on google, but all i could find was how to put values from a column in a single cell, and that's not how it has to be displayed.

So far, my best attempt (which is far from a good one) has been something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE Patient
    (`SIP` int, `name` varchar(10));
INSERT INTO Patient
    (`SIP`, `name`)
VALUES
    (70,'John');

-- A patient can have multiple treatments

CREATE TABLE Treatment
    (`id` int, `SIPFK` int);

INSERT INTO Treatment
    (`id`,`SIPFK`)
VALUES
    (1,70);

-- A treatment can have multiple medicines used while it's open

CREATE TABLE Medicine
    (`Id` int, `Name` varchar(8), `TreatFK` int);

INSERT INTO Medicine
    (`Id`, `Name`, `TreatFK`) 
VALUES
    (7, 'Apples', 1),
    (7, 'Tomatoes', 1),
    (7, 'Potatoes', 1),
    (8, 'Banana', 2),
    (8, 'Peach', 2);


-- The query
select c.id, c.Name, p.id as id2, p.Name as name2, r.id as id3, r.Name as name3 
from Medicine as c, Medicine as p, Medicine as r
where c.id = 7 and p.id=7 and r.id=7;
```

The output I was trying to get was:

```
7 | Apples | 7 | Tomatoes | 7 | Potatoes
```

The table medicines will have more columns than that and i need to show every row related to a treatment in a single row along with the treatment.

But the values keep repeating themselves on different rows and the output on the subsequent columns besides the first ones is not as expected. Also GROUP BY won't solve the problem and DISTINCT doesn't work.

The output of the query is as follows: [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16a05/1)

If any one could give me a hint, I would be grateful.

EDIT: Since access is a derp and won't let me use any good SQL fix nor will recognize DISTINCT to make the data from the queries not repeat themselves, I will try and search for a way to organize the rows directly in the exported excel.

Thank you all for your help, I'll save it cause I'm sure it'll save me hours of hands in the head.

Comment: Perhaps a question here is, why does the med want it in a single row?  Although I will admit that Excel has some fabulous facilities for doing things along a row...

Comment: TBH I'm not entirely sure about his reasons. He said that having it in different lines would mess things up if he wanted to make graphs and that in a single row it would be easier to analyze the data.

Comment: er, I'm pretty sure Excel still mostly operates on a per-row basis.  In fact, given how it can interact with dbs, I'd bet doing things per-row would be easier...  My bet is that his workflow has a pivot table in it (to flip the data), and he doesn't want to deal with adding/removing one.  Or something like that.

Comment: Just came from talking with him, he said he want it for statistic calculation, only one row per treatment. I guess you're right and with excel you can do it easier, but I have not worked that much with excel either, so guess I'll have to start with it right away to find the way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit problemation, because MS Access does not support recursive CTE's and I dont see a way of doing that without Ranking. 
Hence, I have tried to reproduce the results by using subquery which ranks the `Medicines`
and store these into a temporary table.

```
create table newtable
select c.id
, c.Name
,(SELECT COUNT(T1.Name) FROM Medicine AS T1 WHERE t1.id=c.id and T1.Name >= c.Name) AS Rank 
from Medicine as c;
```

Afterwards, it is easy because my query is mostly based on `Ranks` and `IDs`.

```
 select distinct id
,(select Name from newtable t2 where t1.id=t2.id and rank=1) as firstMed
,(select Name from newtable t2 where t1.id=t2.id and rank=2) as secMed
,(select Name from newtable t2 where t1.id=t2.id and rank=3) as ThirdMed
from newtable t1;
```

According to me, the `SELF JOIN` concept and the notion of `recursive CTE's` are the most important points for that particular example and a good practice would be to do a resarch on these.

for reference: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f80a9/2

Comment: Except, this fails if a patient receives more medicines/whatever than he's programmed leafs for.  If he can get a hard upper limit, it's okay to cheat this way.  But for something like this, where chronic care might be happening?  Too likely to add that one extra item...

Comment: I think this might actually work since it's preventive medicine and is unlikely they will use more than the 9 medicaments they specified. But then again, will this work with more columns, or should i recreate the code for every colum I would like to add.

Comment: In my scenario there are only 3 medicines included, so you will have to add as many as you are required to. However, I am not quite familiar with the SQL used in MS Access and perhaps there is more efficient way of doing it which excludes hard coding and hopefully someone will share it.

Comment: This is the way of doing it dynamically in MS SQL, but I am not sure how to modify it for ms access: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/209c3/2

Comment: Hm, access won't let me do the whole "create newtable" thing, and separating the queries still goes on and duplicates the data. Guess I'll have to do as Clockwork says and try approaching the issue more excel. Thanks for your help anyway, I learned at least 3 new things from that code.

Comment: then you can simply alter your main table by adding new column and populate it with the select statement `Update Medicines set Rank=(SELECT COUNT(T1.Name) FROM Medicine AS T1 WHERE t1.id=c.id and T1.Name >= c.Name) from medicines c`.But make sure, that you have a copy of your original table, so if something goes wrong you can always have an alternative.